# Finding the average of an array in assembly (nasm)

Tags: arrays, assembly, average

I have a program that first added everything in the array and printed, now i'm trying to get the average of the array, but i'm having trouble with it.

```
    extern printf                   ; the C function to be called

    SECTION .data                   ; Data section

table           dd               1.0
                dd               1.0
                dd               3.5
                dd               2.0
                dd               1.5
N               equ             ($-table)/4     ; number of items in table


msg     db      "Average = %e",0x0a,0x00
temp    dq      0
;count  dd      0
sum     dd      0       

    SECTION .text                   ; Code section.

    global  main                    ; "C" main program 
main:                                   ; label, start of main program
    mov     ecx, N
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     [count], ecx

        fldz                            ; st0 <- 0
for:    fld     dword [table + ebx*4]   ; st0 <- new value, st1 <- sum of previous
        fadd                            ; st0 <- sum of new plus previous sum   
        inc     ebx
        loop    for

    ;fldz
    fild    dword [count]           ; store count into fpu
    fdiv    st1, st0                ; divide sum by count (N) 

;;; get sum back from FPU
    fstp    dword [sum]             ; put final sum in variable

;;; print resulting sum
    fld     dword [sum]             ; transform z in 64-bit word
    fstp    qword [temp]            ; store in 64-bit temp and pop stack top


    push    dword [temp+4]          ; push temp as 2 32-bit words
    push    dword [temp]
    push    dword msg               ; address of format string
    call    printf                  ; Call C function
    add     esp, 12                 ; pop stack 3*4 bytes

    mov     eax, 1                  ; exit code, 0=normal
    mov     ebx, 0
    int     0x80                    ;
```

The section just after the loop is where i'm trying to divide it.

```
    fild    dword [count]           ; store count into fpu
    fdiv    st1, st0                ; divide sum by count (N)
```

I think i'm getting close, with an array sum of 10, my program gets a result 5, when it should be 2, can anyone help shed some light?

please and thank you :)

Comment: `fild   qword [ecx]` treats `ecx` as a pointer, but it's zero because you just left a `loop`.  You have to store it to memory before you can load it.

Comment: Same error as the duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395802/224132 actually debugged it): you're trying to `fild` a number, but actually using it as an address.

Comment: Edited the question to be more accurate, it's not so much the segmentation error as trying to get the assembly code syntax right to get it to work. @PeterCordes

Comment: You might be overflowing the FP stack with `fld` in the loop.  Actually no, with only 4 elements you won't.  But you should use `fadd dword [table + ebx*4]`.   Your code after the loop is pretty clunky (lots of inefficient storing/reloading), but I don't see right away what's wrong.  Did you try using a debugger to look at values in FP registers before `fdiv`?

Comment: right now after the `fild    dword [count]` the stack reads out 5, which makes sense since I added the # of items in the array (count) into FP. So right now trying to figure out how to divide the sum by that (5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

you need to use `fdivp` that divides st1, by st0

Comment: Oh, you were using `fdiv st1, st0`, which stores the result in `st1` instead of the bottom of the stack.  You could have just used `fidiv dword [count]`.  There's also  `fdivr` and `fdivrp` to store the result in the operand that held the divisor instead of dividend.